# MySQL connection failed error in log file

Tags: python, mysql, logging

I have a question regarding MySQL log file

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using Python and two scenario can occur:

1. connection established successfully or
2. connection failed (due to some reason)

Now I want to find this error in log file, does MySQL create any log file for this kind of error? Or I have to create my own when this error appears

this error doesn't appear in `sql_actions_unconnected.log`, `general.log` `error.log`, any of them

thanks in advance

Comment: I think , you have to create a log whenever this kind of error occurs

Comment: @Coder there is no way to find this error in log file?

Comment: Some connection errors will never be in MySQL logs. If your connection params are wrong (i.e., the wrong address/port/etc) and connection request never hits the MySQL server, naturally those won't be logged

Comment: @WillardSolutions so whenever this error occurs , I have to create my own log, Right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to consistently catch all pertinent error details.

Comment: Ok , thanks , let me wait for a while for ans , otherwise I will prefer your suggestion ! @WillardSolutions

Answer (score 0):

Try to define [`log_warnings`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings) (as a system variable in the settings file or as a command-line option, for instance starting your server with `mysqld --log-warnings=3`) or [`log_error_verbosity`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity) if using MySQL >= 8.0.3.

Note that `log_filter_internal` needs to be enabled, otherwise `log_error_verbosity` has no effect (see the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity)).

If using MariaDB, set [`log_warnings`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#log_warnings) to a value >=1

Hope this helps!