# Mysql doesn't connect to sequel Ace

Tags: sequel

I installed MySQL using Homebrew, the "Server version: 8.3.0 Homebrew", and I would like to connect using Sequel Ace. I am able to connect from the terminal. I also tried adding the following configuration to the file /usr/local/etc/my.cnf:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
mysqlx-bind-address = 0.0.0.0
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Without success, always getting the error:
Unable to connect to host 0.0.0.0, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

> MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' (61) I also
> tried creating an additional user with all privileges, but without
> success.

macOS version: 13.6.4 (22G513)

Comment: Try to define [log_warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings) as mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53890607/724039